# I need to modify my Function based view "FBV" to be class based view "CBV"

Tags: python, django

i need to make some modifications on my code,as i have a function based view and need to change it to be class based view

FBV:

```
def Adress_Use_Prev(request):
      # print(request.POST)
      address_type=request.POST.get('address_type',"shipping")
      address_id=request.POST.get("Address-id")
      request.session[address_type+"_address_id"]=address_id

      next_ = request.GET.get("next")
      next_post = request.POST.get("next")
      redirected_path = next_ or next_post or None
      if is_safe_url(redirected_path, request.get_host()):
          return redirect(redirected_path)

      return redirect("/")
```

what is the best solution to convert this fucntion to be CBV

i tried on the following code, but i failed

```
class UsePrevAddress(NextUrlMixin,FormView):

      # def get_success_url(self):
      #     return self.get_next_url()

     def form_valid(self, form):
          print("test5")
          address_type = self.request.POST.get('address_type', "shipping")
          address_id = self.request.POST.get("Address-id")
          self.request.session[address_type + "_address_id"] = address_id
          return self.get_next_url()

     def form_invalid(self, form):
         super().form_invalid(form)
```

the form.html:

```
{% if address_qs  %}
<form method="POST" action="{% url "cart:checkout-Address-reuse" %}"> {% csrf_token %}
{% for Address in address_qs %}
    <label for="address-{{ Address.id }}">
        <input id="address-{{ Address.id }}" type="radio" name="Address-id" value="{{ Address.id }}"/>
        {{ Address.Address_line_1 }},
        {% if Address.Address_line_2 %} Address.Address_line_2,
        {% endif %}
        {{ Address.State }},{{ Address.Postal_Code }},{{ Address.city }}
    </label><br/>
{% endfor %}



        {% if next_url %}
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next_url }}">
        {% endif %}
         {% if address_type %}
             <input type="hidden" name="address_type" value="{{ address_type }}">
        {% endif %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Use Address</button>
</form>
{% endif %}
```

urls.py:

```
url('^checkout/Address/reuse$',UsePrevAddress.as_view(),name="checkout-Address-reuse"),
```

Comment: Seems like you have already done that. What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: i got that error: NoneType' object is not callable
I'm not sure why that error happens, maybe because I didn't specify the form_class, so the form_class return with None Value.

Comment: Why dont you add the form_class?

Comment: As u see in the form.html i have radio btn and it's value varies regarding the for loop

Comment: No one could help me ?!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a `ModelForm` for the model class. Add `form_class` to your CBV.
Ref: [ModelForm Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)

**Example**

```
from django import forms
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = YourModel
    fields = ('field_1', 'field_2', )

# use `CreateView`. `FormView` is for non-model forms
# and I have used a `ModelForm` here.
class YourModelFormView(NextUrlMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = YourModelForm

    # rest of your code
```